# Windows 10 - Taskbar multiple windows of the same app preview

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

1. I can't see taskbar app previews if there is more than 1 one of them.
   Here are 2 screenshots for reference:

   [image: Example 1]

   [image: Example 2]
2. I can't see the app preview if I hover with my mouse in an application in the taskbar like this:

   [image: Example]

Can someone help me resolve these 2 problems?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have replaced taskbar previews with list view.

List view is a relic from Windows 7 (or older), from when the
taskbar icons didn’t show previews but instead gave a list of the
open windows.

Run `regedit` and navigate to the key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband
```

Check if you can see on the right an item named `NumThumbnails`.
If it exists, right-click it and select "Delete".
Delete also an item named `MinThumbSizePx` if it exists.

If previews are still disabled, check:

- Run *Start > SystemPropertiesPerformance* and enable:
  Enable Peek, Save taskbar thumbnail previews,
  Show thumbnails instead of icons.
- Run `gpedit.msc` and navigate to
  *User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar* and ensure that "Turn off Taskbar Thumbnails" is set
  to anything but Enabled.

Comment: Thanks, it resolved the first problem. What about the second?

Comment: I added more info. How did your Windows get into this state?

Comment: I used a program (Asus GPU Tweak) that disabled some things to increase my computer performance. By the way, the second solution didn't help. I already have those settings on and nothing is set to Enabled in that menu.

Comment: Tweaking products are very dangerous. Does GPU Tweak have an Undo option?

Comment: No, it doesn't. But there has to be a solution, I think.

Comment: When did you use it? Do you have a System Restore backup from before this date?

Comment: I used it a long time ago, and I have a System Restore backup, but it's after the tweak.

Comment: You can try the program for yourself, so you can see for yourself what it does (if you have a tool or something). https://www.asus.com/us/site/graphics-cards/gpu-tweak-ii/

Comment: I wouldn't dare touching it, after your experience. I suggest asking the developer, if he will answer.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help.